Is feature matching useful on full Mahjong set?
I am trying to identify every riichi mahjong tiles in one hand.
I am using OpenCV (on android) and currently I tried ORB and SIFT but even if SIFT had better result its far from usable. I only try to match in grayscale since sometimes colour car differ and I cannot just use OCR since it is not only kanjis.
The end goal would be to take a picture and have all tiles in the picture detected. The tiles would be aligned from left to right properly (as they should be in a mahjong game). If it would be possible to detect them sideways (like the last tiles in the picture) it would be best.
The picture could be taken by anyone so I cannot expect the best focus but I hope that the autofocus would limit this issue. I didn't properly trigger the autofocus in the picture at the bottom.
A riichi mahjong set has :

37 tiles
Some tile with Kanji and some without
Repeated symbol to show the quantity (9 bamboos instead of a number)
One blank tile
3 "Red Five" tiles that are exactly the same as the 5 tiles but with a added dot

A hand can have :

Up to 4 of the same tile
14 tiles total

I quickly saw that since the symbol where repeated there was a very high chance that the "lower" number where detected in higher number tiles. Of course the 2 of bamboo will be found in the 9 of bamboo, just several times.
First, I detected only a few tiles and it work fine. But with the full set I have mostly false positive and it is incredibly slow.
I tried to speed things up by finding the shape of the tiles and applying a mask so that the matching would be focused on there. Its not faster and it seems to break the homography. Is that really not useful ?
I also tried to first detect the more complex one (mostly higher number) and if found, masking them out then keep going through the list. The idea is that if all the nines are found, the two cannot be found in the nine. It improved a bit the results but not much.
In the end, I'm not sure of feature matching is what I need. Are the tiles too complex and to similar to work ? What should I try or look into ?
Under here I took one screenshot of a test, the mask of the test and also the full mahjong set so you can see how tiles look like.





Please edit your question with whether you're trying to identify tiles from any Mahjong set or one particular set, whether you're trying to do this with a physical set (I assume yes), how much tolerance you have to dirt, changes in orientation, defocus (which I see in your picture), tiles that aren't laid out flat (i.e., 14 tiles dumped in a pile), etc.  Note that limiting yourself to tiles arranged neatly, with space around them, and oriented in mostly the same direction will be easiest, and should probably be your starting point regardless of where you want to end up.

@TimWescott Yes, thank you. I agree that it wasn't very clear.
I updated the post but to reiterate : Its Riichi Mahjong set.
The goal is that anyone can take the picture with their phone and the tiles can be found. The tiles should be properly aligned as in a riichi game and the application should call the autofocus before taking the picture (which I did not do).
I cannot expect perfect lighting or perfect focus everytime. Also the tiles will be in a line with very few space (probably none) between tiles.
I also added a cleaner hand.

In about five minutes of searching I found out that if you buy a random "Riichi Mahjong Set" you may get tiles with a white background or a black background, and there's variations in the icons that are perfectly easy for a human to distinguish, but very hard for a machine.  So -- are you going to start with one set and one font, or are you going to start with a goal to buy any Mahjong set that is sold as "Riichi" and expect your algorithm to work?

@TimWescott the goal is to support the most standard one with one background. The one used for WCR competition. Should be extremely similar to the ones here. The wind Kanji font might change a bit.

Have you succeeded in isolating each tile so that you can submit just the tile face to the tile classifier?  That should be doable, and would reduce the workload of the tile classifier.

Yes but as you said the nature of the task means the environment is not controlled enough for the result to be satisfying. I might need to train a model to get the level of precision I want.
